# How to combine multiple rows into one in SQL

Tags: sql

I've probably read a dozen or so similar threads but I have not been able to use them to resolve my issue. I am close, maybe just a step or two away from the solution.

I have a table that I loaded data into which looks similar to this:

```
CustName | Model | Serial | Color | MonthlyCount
Freds    | 123AB | L23456 | BLUE  | 987
Freds    | 123AB | L23456 | GREEN | 1127
Jimmys   | 111SS | L11234 | BLUE  | 2245
Erikas   | 123AB | L11331 | RED   | 12
Erikas   | 123AB | L11331 | BLUE  | 10
Erikas   | 123AB | L11331 | GREEN | 19
```

What I want is to combine them into a single row:

```
CustName | Model | Serial | GreenCount | BlueCount | RedCount
Freds    | 123AB | L23456 | 987        | 1127      |
Jimmys   | 111SS | L11234 |            | 2245      |
Erikas   | 123AB | L11331 | 19         | 10        | 12
```

The Serial numbers are unique so I tried to Inner Join T1 to T2 and T1 to T3 using T1.Serial = T2.Serial and T1.Serial = T3.Serial but I'm still getting rows with NULLS, for example Erikas returns 5 rows, only one of which has all of the data in it

I tried using Where "T1.MonthlyCount"(etc) IS NOT NULL but that didn't filter any rows out:

```
Select T1.CustName
       ,T1.Model 
       ,T1.Serial
       ,(Select T1.MonthlyCount Where T1.Color = 'BLUE') As BlueCount
       ,(Select T2.MonthlyCount Where T2.Color = 'GREEN') As GreenCount
       ,(Select T3.MonthlyCount Where T3.Color = 'RED') As RedCount
From Table1 T1

Inner Join Table2 T2
on T1.Serial = T2.Serial

Inner Join Table3 T3
on T1.Serial = T3.Serial

Where T1.MonthlyCount IS NOT NULL
AND T2.MonthlyCount IS NOT NULL
AND T3.MonthlyCount IS NOT NULL

Group By Serial, CustName, Model, Color, MonthlyCount
```

What I am getting is this:

```
CustName | Model | Serial | GreenCount | BlueCount | RedCount
Freds    | 123AB | L23456 | NULL       | NULL      | NULL
Freds    | 123AB | L23456 | 987        | NULL      | NULL
Freds    | 123AB | L23456 | NULL       | 1127      | NULL
Freds    | 123AB | L23456 | 987        | 1127      | NULL    <--Expected
Jimmys   | 111SS | L11234 | NULL       | NULL      | NULL
Jimmys   | 111SS | L11234 | NULL       | 2245      | NULL    <--Expected
Erikas   | 123AB | L11331 | NULL       | NULL      | NULL
Erikas   | 123AB | L11331 | 19         | NULL      | NULL
Erikas   | 123AB | L11331 | NULL       | 10        | NULL
Erikas   | 123AB | L11331 | NULL       | NULL      | 12
Erikas   | 123AB | L11331 | 19         | 10        | 12      <--Expected
```

I am only looking for the above 3 rows marked as Expected.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Many problems with your current attempt.  However, I would first advise that you google "SQL PIVOT".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select T1.CustName
       ,T1.Model 
       ,T1.Serial
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN Color = 'Blue' THEN MonthlyCount ELSE 0 END) BlueCount
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN Color = 'Green' THEN MonthlyCount ELSE 0 END) GreenCount
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN Color = 'Red' THEN MonthlyCount ELSE 0 END) RedCount
From Table1 T1
Group By Serial, CustName, Model
```

Comment: `'BLUE'` instead of `'Blue'` ;-)

Comment: Results are exactly the same as I posted above.

Comment: @user2233506 this query groups by `CustName,Model,Serial` which means they won't be repeated as in the results above

Comment: This message forced me to add Color to he Group By clause: Column 'Color' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Sorry, after I tried the way you have it structured and it produced the exact same results, I tried wrapping the MonthlyCount of the Case Statement in a SUM which produced the Group By Color issue. You're right, it is not forcing me to group by Color but the results are the same as my original results.

Comment: @user2233506 that's strange. the only thing i can think of is that your data might have differences in `custname,model,serial` that are not obvious (i.e. white spaces or special characters) that are preventing them from being grouped together

Comment: Yeah, I'm stumped now too because your example works on fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91e11/2

Comment: I found my issue. Obviously the sample data isn't my real data and there were many more columns than I added and more aggregate columns...long story short I had one of the aggregate columns in my Group By statement. *Puts on dunce cap*

Answer (score 4):

Use conditional aggregation and only aggregate by the columns you want to be unique in each row.  And, you have way more joins than necessary.  None are needed.

```
Select T1.CustName, T1.Model, T1.Serial,
       sum(case when T1.Color = 'BLUE' then t1.MonthlyCount else 0 end) As BlueCount,
       sum(case when T1.Color = 'GREEN' then t1.MonthlyCount else 0 end) As GreenCount,
       sum(case when T1.Color = 'RED' then t1.MonthlyCount else 0 end) As RedCount
From Table1 T1 
Group By T1.CustName, T1.Model, T1.Serial;
```

If you want `NULL` instead of `0`, remove the `else 0` from each of the clauses.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/891d5) is a SQL Fiddle demonstrating that it works.

Comment: Results are exactly the same as I posted above. Forcing me to add Color to Group By.

Comment: @user2233506 . . . This query will produce only one row for each customer name, model, and serial.  Your results (at the end of the question at least) have these values repeated across rows.  I don't think this produces the same results at all.

Comment: It is forcing me to add Color to Group By which I believe is the reason it is doing so.

Comment: @user2233506 . . . Nothing in this query "forces" you to put `color` in `group by`.  The only references to `color` are as the argument to `sum()`.  Perhaps you copied the query incorrectly when you tested it.

Comment: I had one of my aggregate columns in the group by statement which was causing the rows not to aggregate properly. Thanks for your help.